# Puedo obtener el nombre de la tabla en el que se está ejecutando un TRIGGER DML en ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Estoy aprendiendo Triggers DDL en OracleDB, y quisiera saber cómo obtener el nombre de la tabla en el que se está disparando un Trigger ya que el Trigger se dispara cuando se está haciendo un ALTER en mi schema. Dependiendo del nombre de la tabla se dispara cierto trigger

Tengo el siguiente trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_factura_modificar
BEFORE ALTER ON dbuser.SCHEMA
BEGIN
    IF table_name = 'users_dbuser' THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'NO SE PUEDE MODIFICAR ESTA TABLA');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde sé Oracle no provee una manera de saber el nombre de la tabla donde se dispara el trigger, y pues no se requiere ya un trigger de tabla se define específicamente para 1 (una) tabla.

```
Create or replace trigger trMiTrigger
before alter 
on table miTabla
```

Ahora si lo que desea es que diferentes triggers llamen a un mismo procedimiento
ya sería que pasara como parámetro el nombre de la tabla o si es un procedimiento empaquetado usar una variable global pública a la cual se le asigne desde el cuerpo del trigger el nombre del trigger.